# Azure DocumentDB ARRAY_CONTAINS on nested documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql

It seems like the `ARRAY_CONTAINS` function on nested documents never matches any document.

For example, trying the following simple query with the Azure DocumentDB [Query Playground](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo#Sandbox?SELECT%20*%0AFROM%20food%0AWHERE%20ARRAY_CONTAINS(food.tags.name,%20%22blueberries%22)) would return no result, even if some nested documents should match this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM food
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(food.tags.name, "blueberries")
```

This past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022740/documentdb-query-on-nested-document-and-root-level) on Stack Overflow also infered that this kind of nested query is valid.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument to ARRAY_CONTAINS must be an array. For example, in this case food.tags is valid as an argument, but food.tags.name is not.

Both the following DocumentDB queries are valid and might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT food
FROM food
JOIN tag IN food.tags
WHERE tag.name = "blueberries"
```

Or

```
SELECT food
FROM food
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(food.tags, { name: "blueberries" })
```

Comment: Thank you Aravind, this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Maybe it's worth updating your previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022740/documentdb-query-on-nested-document-and-root-level since it is using the ARRAY_CONTAINS function without an array as the first parameter. I do not have enough reputation to comment it directly.

Comment: Thanks - I've fixed the previous answer